# Python Client Server Transfer .txt Not Writing to File

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, client, file-transfer

I'm trying to write a simple client/server in Python using a TCP socket but I can't seem to figure out why the file is not transferring.

Client:

```
    import socket

    HOST = ''    #server name goes in here
    PORT = 3820             
    socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket.connect((HOST,PORT))

    fileToSend = open('myUpload.txt', 'rb')
    while True:
        data = fileToSend.readline()
        if data:
            socket.send(data)
        else:
            break
    fileToSend.close()
    print 'end'
    socket.close()
    exit()
```

The print end is just to tell me that this client finished.

Server:

```
    import socket
    HOST = ''                 
    PORT = 3820
    socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    socket.listen(1)

    file = open('myTransfer.txt', 'wb')
    while True:
        conn, addr = socket.accept()
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print data
        if data:
            file.write(data)
        else:
            file.close()
            break
    socket.close()

    exit()
```

The server was able to print out the correct data that was sent by the client but it was not able to save it into myTransfer.txt. The program seems to not be able to terminate even though I have a break statement in there. Any help would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Same old, same old. The server does not know when the file ended. It will wait forever.
You need to send the size of the file first, and then use that information in the server to recv exactly that amount of bytes.

See http://code.activestate.com/recipes/408859-socketrecv-three-ways-to-turn-it-into-recvall/

Comment: @BCartolo: The file ends, when the connection is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `accept` inside the while-loop. So you have only one `recv`-call that receives data, so `break` is never called.

Btw. you should use `sendall`, that guarantees, that all data is sent.

Client:

```
import socket

HOST = ''    #server name goes in here
PORT = 3820             
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((HOST,PORT))
with open('myUpload.txt', 'rb') as file_to_send:
    for data in file_to_send:
        socket.sendall(data)
print 'end'
socket.close()
```

Server:

```
import socket
HOST = ''                 
PORT = 3820
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
socket.listen(1)
conn, addr = socket.accept()
with open('myTransfer.txt', 'wb') as file_to_write:
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print data
        if not data:
            break
        file_to_write.write(data)
socket.close()
```

Comment: thanks! That accept was the problem. It is not writing the file but if I input a file with multiple lines says:  
hello  
there  
world  
  
it will only transfer hello. I tried it with both your code and my fixed code.