# Why doesn't my client break out of this while loop?(client server file transfer)

Tags: file, sockets, server, client, transfer

I have this in code in my client which sends a request to the server to send a file.

CLIENT:

```
    filetoopen = tokens[1]
    msg = "RETR " + filetoopen
    sock.send( msg.encode() )
    file2 = open( filetoopen , "w")`

    while True:

        file = sock.recv(1024).decode()

        if(not file or file == '' or len(file) <= 0 ):

            file2.close()
            break
        else:

            file2.write(file) 
            print(file) 

    print("FILE : " , file)
    print("\n File [ " + filetoopen + " ] has been transfered to the current working directory")
    print("from the remote server.\n")
```

SERVER:

```
    openfile = open(file , "r")
    file = openfile.read()

    while (file != ''):
        sock.send(file.encode())
        file = openfile.read()

    openfile.close()

    print("CLOSED FILE")
```

('file' is the file name sent in as parameter)

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [Python Client Server Transfer .txt Not Writing to File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273107/python-client-server-transfer-txt-not-writing-to-file?rq=1)

Comment: Because the server is never closing the socket.